# MySQL select content in multiple languages

Tags: php, mysql

I have one table for generating unique id for translation, named translations_ids
    translation_id (BIGINT)

one table for translations named translations_entries with this structure:
    translation_id (BIGINT) - correspondents to unique translation_id in translations_ids
    table

```
    lang_abbr (varchar 3)
    table_name (varchar 42)
    translated_text (TEXT)
```

table with languages:

```
    lang_abbr (varchar 3)
    language (varchar 36)
    title (varchar 36)
```

Here is table with content (for example news) with this structure:

```
id
title (BIGINT) - correspondents to translation_id in translation_entries table
content (BIGINT) - correspondents to translation_id in translation_entries table
author (varchar 36)
date (varchar36)
```

I tried this:

```
SELECT *
FROM content LEFT JOIN translations_entries ON (content.title = translation_entries.translation_id AND
content.content = translation_entries.translation_id)
WHERE translations_entries.lang_abbr = 'en';
```

but in this way if content no english translation, it wouldn't be displayed in default language

Other way is:

1. `SELECT * FROM content`
2. `Foreach row SELECT * FROM translations_entries WHERE translation_id = this from content AND lang_abbr = 'en'`
3. Check if row exists else new query with default language
4. When data is fetched merge arrays from two tables and display news
   but this way may slow performance

My question is:
    What is the best way to select content from tables in given language and if language translation for this row not exists then select content in
the default language?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry about my first answer it's not a solution. Try this instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM content LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM translations_entries 
WHERE translations_entries.lang_abbr = 'en') AS te 
ON (content.title = te.translation_id AND
content.content = te.translation_id);
```

Comment: BTW: you still have no reputation to vote up or mark an answer as valid, but please leave a comment when you can to let me know if it helped you, I'm interested! Thanks ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this query is similar to my first query. If any row of content have translation only in default language (bg) and no translation in en (english - not default language), translation wouldn't be displayed. I want to select content in en and if en translation no exists for one or more rows then to display them in default language (bg). The second way described in my first post works, but if there is many content this may slow performance, because number of queries will be bigger. Other solution?

Comment: Actually if you put the where clause where I told you it should give a different result, I tried myself, it only affects the part you join, so you should get a row for every element in content table, either with lang_abbr field 'en' or lang_abbr field NULL on those with no 'en' translation. If this is not working then I don't understand your tables structure. Can you explain further your naming convention? why content.title is translation_id and content.content is also translation_id? I think the problem must be in you ON clause... And where do you keep default your default language content?